# Angular 6 ngOnInit first time not working

Tags: jquery, angular

```
ngOnInit() {    
   this.loadScript('assets/js/common.js');

 }

 // Load the scripts with url
public loadScript(url: string) {
  const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = '';
  script.src = url;
  script.async = false;
  script.defer = true;
  body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I added the above code in my component to load my custom js. In the js file i have displayed some jquery element. It is not working in the first time. If i refresh the page it will be working fine. Then i navigate to next page that time also not working. How to fix this issue?

Comment: `ngOnInit` will invoke only once, can you create stackblitz example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: try importing the `<script src='assets/js/common.js'></script>` from the `index.html` and not from ngOnInit(). As index.html will load it, before the file is needed.

Comment: if you want to load `common.js` then inject with `angular.json`.

Comment: If i add this script to index.html or angular json script not working in the first time

Comment: You might need to use `ngAfterViewInit` as discussed here - https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/angular2-how-to-load-external-javascript-file-dynamically/259478/7

Answer (score 0):

simular problem, not solved with the ngAfterViewInit. The javascript is called, but is not working the first time. When I reload the page, it keeps working the whole time. The javascript is manipulating the DOM.

Here is the code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var ImageMap: any

function InitImageMapping()
{
  ImageMap('img[usemap]')
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buildingoverview',
  templateUrl: './buildingoverview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buildingoverview.component.css']
})
export class BuildingoverviewComponent implements OnInit {


  message = "Click on the image!";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Mss moet ik dit verplaatsen naar een ander event?


  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log("InitMaps")
    InitImageMapping();
  }

  clickImage(id: string)
  {
    this.message = `clicked on:${id}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got this working by using a delay of 200 ms before launching the script, the new code is this:

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this working now, just inserting a delay of 200 ms.
Code looks like this now:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
declare var ImageMap: any

function InitImageMapping()
{

  ImageMap('img[usemap]')
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buildingoverview',
  templateUrl: './buildingoverview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buildingoverview.component.css']
})
export class BuildingoverviewComponent implements OnInit {


  message = "Click on the image!";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Mss moet ik dit verplaatsen naar een ander event?


  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log("InitMaps")
    timer(200).subscribe(x => { InitImageMapping()})
  }

  clickImage(id: string)
  {
    this.message = `clicked on:${id}`
  }
}
```